# Conformal Mapping onto the Unit Disc

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

> Given the open vertical strip $G=\{x+iy~|~0<x<1,~-\infty<y<\infty\}$, what is the explicit conformal injective map characterizing $w=f(z):G\to\mathbb{D}$?

It is noted that if there exists a mapping $w=M(z):G\to\mathbb{H}$, where $\mathbb{H}=G=\{x+iy~|y>0, (x,y)\in\mathbb{R}\}$. Therefore, the composition of $w=M(z)$ with the Cayley transform given by $\kappa(z):z\to \frac{z+i}{z-i}$, namely $\kappa(w(z)):w\to \frac{w+i}{w-i}$ is such a conformal mapping. However, what is the particular  $w=M(z):G\to\mathbb{H}$?

Comment: $z \mapsto e^{i\pi z}$.

Comment: How would you prove this or show that $w=M(z):G\to\mathbb{H}$, where $w=M(z)=e^{i\pi z}$? @MikeMiller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll fill in the details of the comment and write out the full solution:

I'm going to leave it as a composition of maps. First, let $f_1(z)=\pi z,$ which brings us from $G$ to the strip $\Sigma=\{z:\ \Re z\in (0,\pi)\}.$ As the previous comment suggested, let's consider $f_2(z)=e^{iz}.$ By Euler's formula, if $z=x+iy,$ then $f_2(z)=e^{-y}\left(\cos x+i\sin x\right).$ Here, $x\in (0,\pi),$ so $\cos x\in (-1,1)$ and $\sin x\in (0,1).$ Also, $y\in \mathbb{R},$ and so $e^{-y}\in \mathbb{R},$ as well. Hence, $\Re f_2(z)\in \mathbb{R},$ and $\Im f_2(z)\in (0,\infty)$ (all bijectively, clearly). Thus, $f_2$ sends $\Sigma$ to the upper half plane $H$. The standard map $f_3(z)=\frac{z-i}{z+i}$ sends $H$ to the unit disk $D_1(0).$ In total, the composition $F=f_3\circ f_2\circ f_1$ sends $G$ to the unit disk.

I know that this is an old question, but it's a fairly standard problem, so hopefully this write-up helps anyone else who might come across the same exercise with the same confusions.